# C# листбоксы, листы, и траблы с ними. Работает одна конструкция, а другая нет. Подробнее в теме

Tags: c#, list, listbox

Есть код,

```
        List<object> tmp = new List<object>();
        foreach (object Item in listBoxPlaneType.SelectedItems) tmp.Add(Item);
        foreach (object Item in tmp) listBoxPlaneType.Items.Remove(Item);
        tmp.Clear();
```

который очень хорошо удаляет выделенные элементы из листбокса `listBoxPlaneType`

а вот это "макраме" выдает outofrange

```
        List<object> tmp = new List<object>();
        List<int> tmp2 = new List<int>();

        foreach (object Item in listBoxPlaneType.SelectedItems) 
        tmp.Add(Item);
        foreach (int Item2 in listBoxPlaneType.SelectedIndices) 
        tmp2.Add(Item2);

        foreach (object Item in tmp) listBoxPlaneType.Items.Remove(Item);
        foreach (int Item2 in tmp2) listBoxNumber.Items.RemoveAt(Item2);

        tmp.Clear();
        tmp2.Clear();
```

Которое должно удалять и из первого листбокса выделенные итемы( что оно  и делает), и из второго листбокса удалять итемы, по адресам выделенным в первом листбоксе. 
[image: Вот эти два листбокса] Выбираешь полное название и удаляешь, то справа должен удалиться и номер. 
Иногда не выкидывает с ошибкой, но удаляет из номерного листа не те.

Знаю, что там чутка проблема с обращением по индексу (надеюсь на это), но смещение на +1 и -1 не помогает.

UPD: Добавил результат [image: результат] работы с ошибкой, если пытаюсь удалить Ил 2 и Изгой 1

Comment: А что в дебагере? Выполнять код можно и по шагам

Comment: Ну вот в дебагере до меня не доходит как правильно поставить точки остановки в форич'е и в индексах запутался.

Comment: `tmp.Clear();` думаешь GC глупее тебя?

Comment: На какой строке ошибка?

Comment: @alex78191 Нет, не думаю что глупее, я скопировал этот первоначальный скрипт с инета, ибо задолбался реализовывать сам. Все время что то мешало,и о чудо - работает. Но теперь нужно добавить в этот алгоритм паралельное удаление. Добавил скрин с ошибкой и отладчиком в вопрос.

Comment: `RemoveAt` удаляет по индексу. После удаления одного элемента, индексы остальных меняются.

Comment: Надо сначала получить объекты из второго списка, а потом удалять не по индексу, а по объекту.

Comment: @Alex78 Додумаля одновременно с вами. Задал себе вопрос- НУ ПОЧЧЕМУ ТЫ НЕ МОЖЕШЬ УДАЛИТЬ 4й ЭЛЕМЕНТ ЛИСТБОКСА, А?, А потом понял, что 4го уже нету в помине.

Comment: Поэтому надо удалять в обратном цикле с убыванием индексов!

Comment: @alex78 в обратном цикле не получится- индексы сдвигаются все равно. Удалит не тот объект.

Comment: Тоже так ошибался

Comment: @elislavkat Ты откуда знаешь? Ты уже ошибся. Надо foreach по `tmp2.Reverse()` делать.

Comment: Ой-вей! Не забывайте кошерный `for` (в обратную сторону, да).

Comment: @alex78 добавилю сейчас ответ. Можно конечно и в обратном порядке удалять, но если удалять по итемам а не индексам, то без разницы.

Comment: @elislavkat Я про индексы и говорил

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я написал про него https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673541/c-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%9f?noredirect=1#comment981100_673541

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
var indices = listBoxPlaneType.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().Reverse().ToList();
foreach (int i in indices)
{
    listBoxPlaneType.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    listBoxNumber.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Можно просто `Reverse()` и в `ToList()` конвертировать необязательно.

Comment: @Alex78191: Точно! Забыл про него, спасибо!

Comment: @Alex78191: А конвертировать, боюсь, обязательно, а то иначе мы ж удаляем из коллекции во время итерирования по ней.

Comment: Мы indices используем просто для получения итератора индексов.

Comment: @Alex78191: Ну да, но первый же `listBoxPlaneType.Items.RemoveAt(i)` очевидно должен изменить коллекцию `listBoxPlaneType.SelectedIndices`, разве нет? А итерировать по меняющейся коллекции нельзя, вылетит.

Comment: мы создали новую коллекцию.

Comment: [How does IEnumerable<T>.Reverse work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051612/how-does-ienumerablet-reverse-work)

Comment: @Alex78191: Ага, понимаю. В любом случае, код не имеет право рассчитывать на подробности имплементации `Reverse`. Тем более, код при этом становится _хрупким_, так что я бы всё же не пожалел одной материализации.

Comment: КВС объект типа IEnumerable не может быть изменен, а только создан новый.

Comment: @Alex78191: Это вы к чему?

Comment: К тому, что метод Reverse() не может изменить объект типа IEnumerable Независимо от реализации.

Comment: @Alex78191: Ну это вроде бы тут ни при чём. `Where` вот тоже не может изменить исходный список, однако вот такой код: http://ideone.com/GWM2RR вылетает.

Comment: При чем тут `IList<T>`, я про `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Alex78191: Ну, `Where` не изменяет ни `IList<T>`, ни `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Я могу так же сказать, что при обращении к элементу массива по индексу с использованием оператора `[]` массив можно изменить. Такой же комментарий по информативности.

Comment: @vladD [скриншот с ошибкой](https://yadi.sk/i/0qJUd9_23JjcjL)

Comment: @elislavkat: И правда. Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<object> tmp = new List<object>();
        List<object> tmp2 = new List<object>();

        foreach (object Item in listBoxPlaneType.SelectedItems) tmp.Add(Item);
        foreach (int Item in listBoxPlaneType.SelectedIndices) tmp2.Add(listBoxNumber.Items[Item]);

        foreach (object Item in tmp) listBoxPlaneType.Items.Remove(Item);

        foreach (object Item in tmp2) listBoxNumber.Items.Remove(Item);

        tmp.Clear();
        tmp2.Clear();
```

Код выполняет все замечательно. Проблема, как подсказали мне в комментах, была в том, что удаляя один итем по индексу, итемов становится меньше, пытаюсь удалить итем 4, хотя в листе уже нету 4х итемов, и нумерации к тому же изменилась. Нужно создать 2й лист tmp2 не с индексами, а с итемами из 2го листбокса(только те что выделены слева), и удалять по этим итемам.